# Secure LDAP authentication

Tags: c++, windows, ldap

I would like to authenticate securely from C++ client application with OpenLDAP server, for example, using SSL/TLS or SASL. I use Windows 7 64-bit operating system.

I tried this example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366105%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

But it fails in this function call:
ULONG ldapConn = ldap_connect(pLdapConnection, NULL);

The return code from ldap_connect is 81 (dec).

I have installed OpenLDAP to my computer from here:

http://www.userbooster.de/en/download/openldap-for-windows.aspx

I use 127.0.0.1 (localhost) as the host.

OpenLDAP debug log looks like this:
TLS trace: SSL_accept:SSLv3 flush data
tls_read: want=5 error=Unknown error
TLS trace: SSL_accept:error in SSLv3 read client certificate A
TLS trace: SSL_accept:error in SSLv3 read client certificate A
daemon: activity on 1 descriptor
daemon: waked
daemon: WSselect: listen=2 active_threads=0 tvp=NULL
daemon: WSselect: listen=3 active_threads=0 tvp=NULL

According to the log it seems that this is somehow related to certificates. The OpenLDAP configuration is the about default from the installation package, for example:

TLSVerifyClient never
TLSCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:-SSLv2
TLSCertificateFile ./secure/certs/server.pem
TLSCertificateKeyFile ./secure/certs/server.pem
TLSCACertificateFile ./secure/certs/server.pem

Does someone know why ldap_connect fails?

Or does someone know a useful tutorial or C++ code example concerning this topic? It is especially unclear to me how the client certificates are linked to the client code. In other words, how it is defined in the client C++ code, where the certificates are obtained during the authentication.

BR, 
Tuomo

Answer (score 0):

Found this article: http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-technical/200903/msg00061.html.  Looks like you might want to change out TLSCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:-SSLv2 to TLSCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:+SSLv2.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I updated the OpenLDAP server slapd.conf file as you proposed (TLSCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:+SSLv2) but it seems that it still does not work.
The ldap_connect(pLdapConnection, NULL) call still returns value 81 and the openLDAP debug log looks like (sorry about the formatting):  
TLS trace: SSL_accept:SSLv3 flush data  <br/>
tls_read: want=5 error=Unknown error  <br/>
TLS trace: SSL_accept:error in SSLv3 read client certificate A  <br/>
TLS trace: SSL_accept:error in SSLv3 read client certificate A  <br/>
daemon: activity on 1 descriptor  <br/>
daemon: waked <br/>

Comment: Do you have some other ideas? Do you see certificates as a potential problem or is the problem somewhere else as I have configured "TLSVerifyClient never" in slapd.conf? Or could system domains cause some problems?